# Get column headers from custom dropdowns

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I have a Handsontable with some headers that are custom drop-downs.

Here is what they look like:

```
var txt= "<select id='Value_0'><option value='None'>N/A</option><option value='Name'>Name</option><option value='Long/E'>N/Lat</option><option value='Lat/N'>E/Long</option><option value='State'>State</option><option value='Zone'>Zone</option><option value='Hem'>Hem</option></select>";

hot2 = new Handsontable(container2, {
    data:d,
    columns: [
      {renderer: customRenderer},
      {renderer: customRenderer},
      {renderer: customRenderer},
      {renderer: customRenderer},
      {renderer: customRenderer},
      {renderer: customRenderer},
      {renderer: customRenderer},
      {renderer: customRenderer}
    ],
  colHeaders:[txt,txt,txt,txt,txt,txt,txt], 
  rowHeaders: true,
  minSpareCols: 1,
  //always keep at least 1 spare row at the right
  minSpareRows: 20,
  //always keep at least 1 spare row at the bottom,
  contextMenu: true,
  columnSorting: true,
  search: true
});
```

What I want to do is get a list of the column headers (preferably in an array) then see what order the drop-downs were selected.  Here's the code for that:

```
colLocs = $("container2").handsontable("getColHeader");

LatColumn = colLocs.indexOf("N/Lat");  //Yin
LongColumn = colLocs.indexOf("E/Long"); //Xin
ZoneColumn = colLocs.indexOf("Zone"); //Zone
StateColumn = colLocs.indexOf("State"); //Zone
```

What I get now is colLocs to be undefined.

Any help on this would be appreciated.  Thanks

## Update

Fiddle, more or less like how I have implemented it: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8zughy0q/2/)

I think what the problem is, to make this setup work, I need to have the whole table in an event listener which isolates it from the other function call.  So when the function tries to read the headers it can't reach it.

This is a link to the example on their page: [Handsontable custom Headers](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.0/demo-custom-renderers.html#page-header)

Answer (score 0):

Well the thing is that `getColHeader` returns an array of your headers. If you look at what your headers look like, it's the entire HTML string. Doing `array.indexOf` will find perfect matches of your array elements. For example,

```
["aa","a"].indexOf("a");
```

will return `1`, not `0`, because the first time the element `"a"` shows up is the second element of the array. So, what you want is to ask for `indexOf` on each individual element with something like a `forEach` loop.

```
colLocs = $("container2").handsontable("getColHeader");

colLocs.forEach(function(header, index) {
    var latIndex = header.indexOf("N/Lat");
    if (latIndex > -1) {LatColumn = index}; // set it to the index of the for loop
    ...
}
```

Notice that this is messy code as is your definition of the colHeaders. I suggest instead of those long switch cases, that you just define the array.

Comment: As my code is, the colLocs is undefined meaning the right side also undefined. Doing your forEach would result in nothing keeping the above the same.   Thanks for the tip on cleaning up the code though.

Comment: the right side would throw an exception if that were the case, but ok. Instead of doing `colLocs = $("container2").handsontable("getColHeader");`, do `hot2.getColHeader()` and tell us what you get from that

Comment: I actually tried that as well... This is the console error I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handsontable' of undefined"

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle because that doesn't make sense. If your `hot2` variable is defined, then `hot2.getColHeader()` would not through a `handsontable` undefined error

Comment: If I take everything out of the addEventListener function then I get an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null" which occurs on this line: `hot2 = new Handsontable(container2, {`

Comment: Ok thanks for the fiddle. First off, you have hot2.handsontable('getColHeader') which is blatantly wrong. `hot2` is your handsontable instance, it's not a jquery selector, so you would just do as I wrote on the second comment, hot2.getColHeader() . And your problem is with context. You defined `hot2` as a `var` twice and in the wrong place. Your `check` function doesn't have access to that variable. I recommend passing it in or having a global object carry that variable. It works when I remove the declarations on `hot2`: http://jsfiddle.net/89ooafah/

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I didn't have the code the way you said.  However, now using this: `colLocs.forEach(function(header) {
        var latIndex = header.indexOf("N/Lat");
        if (latIndex > -1) {LatColumn = latIndex};  //=111
        var lonIndex = header.indexOf("E/Long");
        if (lonIndex > -1) {LongColumn = lonIndex};  //=147
        var zonIndex = header.indexOf("Zone");
        if (zonIndex > -1) {ZoneColumn = zonIndex};  //=213
        var staIndex = header.indexOf("State");
        if (staIndex > -1) {StateColumn = staIndex};   //=177` no matter which col they are in

Comment: No, It doesn't work. No matter which column order I choose from the dropdowns the index values are always the same. This doesn't indicate which column has been designated the dropdown that has been selected. All that your code does is tell me which index in the html string the text is which is always the same. It doesn't tell me which is actually selected. Nice try though.

Comment: Well of course that's what it's doing, you use the index of the for loop to tell you which position you're at.

Comment: but when the header is exactly the same each time, what good does that do?  doing this: `console.log(header)` in the loop yields: `<select id='Value_6'><option value='None'>N/A</option><option value='Name'>Name</option><option value='Long/E'>N/Lat</option><option value='Lat/N'>E/Long</option><option value='State'>State</option><option value='Zone'>Zone</option><option value='Hem'>Hem</option></select>` the index is the position in the string and its the same every time

Comment: Look at your own fiddle. the header is the same each time it looks.